# How to add custom header and i should access only through https in apache 2.0

Tags: apache2, putty

I have configured http and https with different port number in apache2.0 and now i need to add custom header called headerssl and this header must say `"hi it took D=345 microsecond to serve you."` It should be accessible only through https site.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this mod_ssl guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/ssl/ssl_howto.html) to setup an SSL enabled site, a default Apache installation includes a sample SSL site for reference. You may use that as a starting point and customize it for your configuration.

Refer to [this mod_headers guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) to configure custom headers. Use the following syntax with mod_headers, but place this line within an SSL config, see the example below:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www.example.com.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www.example.com.key"

    Header set headerssl "Hi it took D = %D microseconds to serve you"

</VirtualHost>
```